# Cloud Foundry + JPA + Spring + EntityManager

Tags: database, jpa, cloud-foundry

I want to deploy a Web based WAR into CloudFoundry using a cloud datasource.

I have defined a bean like this:

```
       <cloud:data-source id="dataSource"/>      
       <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
            <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myPersistenceUnit" />
            <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
                   <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
                     <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
                     <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>

                  </bean>
            </property>           
        </bean> 
   </beans>
```

....but when i try to deploy I obtain a Java Agent exception :
Cannot apply class transformer without LoadTimeWeaver specified

But i can't specfy a Java Agent whithout uploading a jar instrument agent.....

Any solution??

Answer (score 1):

I'm not that familiar with EclipseLink, so I'm not even sure that the weaver requirement comes from EclipseLink, BUT

One way of doing this would be to deploy your app as a standalone app (*i.e.* deploy your own tomcat around it), that way you can put the extra weaver jar in `lib/`.
Have a look at http://blog.cloudfoundry.org/2012/06/18/deploying-tomcat-7-using-the-standalone-framework/ and https://github.com/ericbottard/cloudfoundry-tomcat-7

Also, if you only have one DataSource, you can avoid using the cloudfoundry-specific `<cloud:datasource />` namespace by just uploading your regular app and have Cloud Foundry *auto reconfigure* your app (info here: http://blog.springsource.org/2011/11/04/using-cloud-foundry-services-with-spring-part-2-auto-reconfiguration/) As a matter of fact, this may be the way to have EclipseLink work seamlessly on Cloud Foundry (my guess here)

And of course, there's also the option of switching to another provider that doesn't require class instrumentation, but that's a bit extreme.

Again, I'm not an Eclipse Link guru, so I may be missing something here...